# Error in using FileZilla

Tags: windows-xp, filezilla

- I have windows-xp as o/s with version sp2 in my laptop.
- In this, I have installed filezilla in it.
- But after some time my laptop will automatically restarts and showing
  RAM error in it (Blue Screen appears).
- Any kind of help will be appreciated.

--
Thanks

Comment: Ok any other option. Can we use Filezilla's another version here.

Comment: If the system is crashing you should make sure that FileZilla is the cause. Anyway, which FileZilla version are you currently using? Keep in mind Microsoft has ended support for Windows XP, and FileZilla doesn't support it either any more. According to the [official forum](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7089), you should use version 3.7.3 on XP and disable updates.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of filezilla.

Comment: Latest version is `3.8.0`, and it doesn't support XP. Uninstall it and get [version 3.7.3](http://download.filezilla-project.org/). Then the system shouldn't crash any more.

Comment: Ok I will try and then check what will happen ....

Comment: How do you know that FileZilla is making this problem. Have you tried to use SP3?

Comment: As when I install and do work on it then after 5 to 10 minutes Computer will restart. No I have SP2.